How to keep a pipe open and discard data while the reader is blocked?
I have a camera capture program and video streaming program working together as rpicam-vid ... | go2rtc. My problem is that go2rtc only reads data from the pipe when someone opens the video stream, but I need rpicam-vid to run continuously even when the stream is not up. Is there a way to simply discard data when the reader is not pulling data?

There is a reader on the pipe: go2rtc. If it's not reading because of some other external reason, maybe fake that reason somehow? Or can you get it to exit if there are no open video streams? If you can do the latter, then maybe you can do something like: ...  | while true; do timeout 1 cat > /dev/null; go2rtc --option-quit-if-no-open-streams; done

You're right, I have updated the question. I could add a fake stream client but that will use unnecessary CPU. I need go2rtc to run constantly and listen for connections, it's just that the user won't be tuned in all the time.

You could insert something in between ripcam-vid and go2rtc that forwards the data with the output in non-blocking mode so that when the pipe is full because nothing is reading from it, the data is discarded (the write()s to the pipe just fail with EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)¹):
rpicam-vid ... | {
 dd count=0 oflag=nonblock status=none &&
   PERLIO=:unix perl -pe 'BEGIN{$/ = \8192}'
} | go2rtc

Here using dd (assumed to be the GNU implementation of dd) to change stdout to non-blocking mode and perl to forward the data in chunks of up to 8KiB.
By default on Linux, the pipe buffer size is 64KiB, you can enlarge it to make it less likely for data to be discarded in normal operation using the F_SETPIPE_SZ fnctl. For instance, doing both the non-block and pipe capacity enlargement with perl:
rpicam-vid ... |
  PERLIO=:unix perl -MFcntl=F_GETFL,F_SETFL,O_NONBLOCK,F_SETPIPE_SZ -pe '
    BEGIN{
      $flags = fcntl(STDOUT, F_GETFL, 0) || die "getfl: $!\n";
      fcntl(STDOUT, F_SETFL, $flags | O_NONBLOCK) || die "setfl: $!\n";
      fcntl(STDOUT, F_SETPIPE_SZ, 1048576) || die "setpipesz: $!\n";
      $/ = \8192;
    }' | go2rtc

The maximum pipe size value one may use is determined by /proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size (sysctl fs/pipe-max-size), 1MiB by default, which you can raise as root with sysctl -w fs/pipe-max-size="$newvalue" if need be.
But I'm not sure discarding chunks of a video like that is a good idea.

¹ non-blocking mode could also mean short writes, that is, when writing to the pipe that is almost full, only as much as can fit in the pipe be written, the rest discarded if not reattempted.

This does solve my stated problem, but you're correct about the video stream breaking. I will explore other options. Thank you.
